# Fetch response not being handled

Tags: reactjs, react-router, response, fetch-api

I'm creating a fetch request, that looks similar to this:

```
fetch('/endpoint', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then((response) =>{
      if(response.ok){
        console.log("Response was ok");
        back();
      }
     else {
      const result = response.json();
      result.then((result) => alert(result.message))
     }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

For reference, this is the back function:

```
const back = () => {
    navigate('/dashboard')
  }
```

I would like the user to be routed back to a dashboard component after the request is complete. The back function executed properly when just tied to a button, and if there is an issue with the response, the issue does display as an alert. But why does the block containing the console log and back() not execute when the response is ok?

Comment: need more detail . can you provide your code in code-sandbox or else where

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem was in the back end. The response was returning a status, but no jsonified object:

```
router.delete('/route', controller.delete, (req, res) => {
  return res
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .status(200)
})
```

Before

```
router.delete('/route', controller.delete, (req, res) => {
  return res
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .status(200).json();
})
```

After

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).